# Form executando após fechado

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho uma aplicação com um *Form1*, onde está minha *pictureBox*. Adicionei um outro *Form2* ao projeto que ao executá-lo ele vira uma lente de aumento, assim, da pra usar em cima do primeiro *Form1*.

Meu problema é: após pressionar *ESC* que é a tecla que da o `Close()` no *Form2* (lente), a lente realmente desaparece, mas a aplicação continua consumindo memória e processador referente ao *Form2* (lente) como se ele apenas estivesse escondido.

O *Form2* tem um erro que gera uma *exception* ao mover o mouse muito ao canto da tela quando a lente está ligada. E este erro ainda ocorre mesmo com ele fechado após pressionar *ESC*.

O problema está em como estou chamando o *Form2*?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   new Form2().Show(); 
}
```

Ou em como ele está sendo fechado com `Close()` ?

Segue o código do *Form2* (lente):

```
PictureBox pictureBox1 = new PictureBox(); // Have a picture box
int zoom = 1; // Variable for zoom value
public Form2()
{
    pictureBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; // Occupy the full area of the form
    pictureBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle; // Have a single border of clear representation
    Controls.Add(pictureBox1); // Add the control to the form
    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None; // Make the form borderless to make it as lens look

    Timer timer = new Timer(); // Have a timer for frequent update
    timer.Interval = 100; // Set the interval for the timer
    timer.Tick += timer_Tick; // Hool the event to perform desire action
    timer.Start(); //Start the timer
    printscreen = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height); // Have a bitmap to store the image of the screen         
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(printscreen as Image); // Get the image of the captured screen
    graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, printscreen.Size); // Get the copy of screen
    var position = Cursor.Position; // Get the position of cursor
    var lensbmp = new Bitmap(50, 50); // Have a bitmap for lens
    var i = 0; // Variable for row count
    var j = 0; // Variable for column count
    for (int row = position.X - 25; row < position.X + 25; row++) // Indicates row number
    {
        j = 0; // Set column value '0' for new column
        for (int column = position.Y - 25; column < position.Y + 25; column++) // Indicate column number
        {
            lensbmp.SetPixel(i, j, printscreen.GetPixel(row, column)); // Place current region pixel to lens bitmap
            j++; // Increase row count
        }
        i++; // Increase column count
    }
    this.pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(lensbmp, lensbmp.Width * zoom, lensbmp.Height * zoom); // Assign lens bitmap with zoom level to the picture box
    Size = pictureBox1.Image.Size; // Assign optimal value to the form
    Left = position.X + 20; // Place form nearer to cursor X value
    Top = position.Y + 20; // Place form nearer to cursor Y value
    TopMost = true; // Keep the form top level
}

// Override OnKeyDown for zoom in and zoom out actions
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyValue == 73) // Set "i" as the key for Zoom In.
        zoom++; // Increase zoom by 1 item greater
    else if (e.KeyValue == 79) // Set "o" as the key for Zoom Out
        zoom--; // Decrease zoom by 1 item smaller
    else if (e.KeyValue == 27) // Set "Esc" to close the magnifier
    {
        Close(); // Close the form
        Dispose(); // Dispose the form
    }
    base.OnKeyDown(e);
}
```

Comment: Tenta usar this.Close();

Comment: Já havia tentado com this. Não muda nada. Obrigado pela dica, amigo.

Comment: Tenta mudar esses if's pra um Switch e em vez de colocar o valor inteiro da tabela ASCII voce coloca KeyCode.O por exenplo pra pegar a leva O entendeu ?

Comment: coloque mais informações do form2, principalmente a forma com que ele "pega" a imagem do form1 para dar zoom

Comment: coloquei o codigo do Form2 na pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provavelmtente é o seu `Timer` que ainda está em execução em alguma *thread*.

Primeiramente declare seu `Timer` como variável de classe para que seja possível acessá-la posteriormente:

```
PictureBox pictureBox1 = new PictureBox(); // Have a picture box
int zoom = 1; // Variable for zoom value
Timer timer;  // Have a timer for frequent update

public Form2()
{
    pictureBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; // Occupy the full area of the form
    pictureBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle; // Have a single border of clear representation
    Controls.Add(pictureBox1); // Add the control to the form
    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None; // Make the form borderless to make it as lens look

    timer = new Timer() // Cria o timer definido anteriormente
    timer.Interval = 100; // Set the interval for the timer
    timer.Tick += timer_Tick; // Hool the event to perform desire action
    timer.Start(); //Start the timer
    printscreen = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height); // Have a bitmap to store the image of the screen         
}
```

Na hora de fechar o form, pare o `Timer` (*timer*) e dê um `Dispose()` no mesmo:

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyValue == 73) // Set "i" as the key for Zoom In.
        zoom++; // Increase zoom by 1 item greater
    else if (e.KeyValue == 79) // Set "o" as the key for Zoom Out
        zoom--; // Decrease zoom by 1 item smaller
    else if (e.KeyValue == 27) // Set "Esc" to close the magnifier
    {
        // Encerra a execução do timer
        timer.Stop();
        timer.Dispose();
        Close(); // Close the form
        Dispose(); // Dispose the form
    }
    base.OnKeyDown(e);
}
```